# Pass dialog title variable in jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to pass the title of the jQuery dialog variably.

I am trying to use the "data" property like this:

```
jQuery( "#dialog" ).data( 'the_title', 'John Doe Dialog' ).dialog( "open" );
    
jQuery( function() {

    jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({       

        title: jQuery( "#dialog" ).data( 'the_title' ), 

    });

});
```

But it is not working, it is displaying the default title.

Any thought please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly specify any of the dialogue options [documented here](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/),
`title` being one such, I've added another couple of options as further examples.

```
jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    title: 'John Doe Dialog',
    width: '100px',
    height: '50px'
});
```

You can also specify any option after the dialog is created

```
$('#dialog').dialog();
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'wibble');
```

hence you can use this chaining style of code:

```
$('#dialog').dialog().dialog('option', 'title', 'wibble');
```

Comment: Of course it worked. I love you pal. Thank you